# Phonegap CLI will not recognise plugin command

Tags: android, cordova, command, command-line-interface

I'm trying to using **plugin** command at Phonegap CLI.
I have been using create 'command to create projects and its fine so I assume my config of paths etc is ok?

plugin is not recognised as an internal or external command. (I'm trying to install sqlite plugin)

Also 'phonegap'is not recognised at command prompt - I can use create command in command prompt from bin directory in phonegap directory.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) and then Phonegap (through nodeJS).

To install Phonegap, type, in a regular cmd promt (once NodeJS is installed)

```
npm install -g phonegap
```